# Tagging groups of sequential hours over multiple days

Tags: r

In R, I am looking at data that shows simulated power system outages and need a way to tag continuous outages. The data are hourly, so I am looking for something that can recognize sequential hours and then breaks in the sequence. I am having trouble tagging outages that stretch out over midnight.

I have tried a couple approaches, but keep running into issues with outages that extend multiple days. For example, I can tag a 12 hour outage that runs from hour 8 to hour 20, but it splits up the tag if the outage runs from say, hour 20 on day 1 to hour 12 on day 2 (these end up looking like 2 different, shorter, outages).

```
month day hour outage_tag
1      2   23   1
1      2   24   1
1      3   1    1
1      3   2    1
3      5   13   2
3      5   14   2
3      5   15   2
```

The goal is to create the outage_tag column shown above. I am having trouble creating the tags that wraps around midnight (tag 1 in the example would be broken into 2 different tags, which is not useful). I have the data to create a year-month-day-hour date if needed.

Any help (or suggestions for improving this question) would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If outages can extend from February to March then we will have to know the year as well so assuming that `year` stores the year convert to POSIXct using `ISOdatetime`, take successive differences, compare to 1 hour and take the cumulative sum.

```
year <- 2000
transform(DF, outage_tag = 
  cumsum(c(1, diff(ISOdatetime(year, month, day, hour-1, 0, 0, tz = "GMT")) != 1)))
```

giving:

```
  month day hour outage_tag
1     1   2   23          1
2     1   2   24          1
3     1   3    1          1
4     1   3    2          1
5     3   5   13          2
6     3   5   14          2
7     3   5   15          2
```

### Note

```
DF <- structure(list(month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L), day = c(2L, 
 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L), hour = c(23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 13L, 14L, 
 15L)), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```